# pygtk3 entrycompletion style

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I'm currently testing python and gtk3, my concern is about how to implement a style (with CSS) to modify the font (and also maybe the line focused) of the GtkEntryCompletion opened list.

I can modify a GtkEntry font and behavior with CSS style, but did not find the way for the completion list.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The completion list is implemented internally as a [GtkTreeView](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html) so, in my opinion, the more appropriate way to style it is:

```
.entry GtkTreeView {
    /* Your specific style customizations here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style it with the following

```
entry treeview {
  background-color: #00ff55;
}
```

That example will turn the background a horrible green :-)